# Installing VirtualBox on Fedora 20 but kernel mismatch

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox

**1)** Hi i am trying to install virtualbox.
but something is wrong with my kernel, the commands below always mismatch.

[ ~]# uname -r

**3.15.6-200.fc20.i686+PAE**

[root@amidala ~]# rpm -qa | grep kernel

kernel-PAE-modules-extra-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686

abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.2.2-1.fc20.i686

kernel-headers-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686

kernel-modules-extra-3.15.6-200.fc20.i686

**kernel-PAE-devel-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686**

kernel-devel-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686

kernel-PAE-3.15.6-200.fc20.i686

kernel-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686

kernel-PAE-modules-extra-3.15.6-200.fc20.i686

kernel-modules-extra-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686

kernel-PAE-3.13.5-202.fc20.i686

kernel-PAE-modules-extra-3.13.5-202.fc20.i686

kernel-3.15.6-200.fc20.i686

kernel-PAE-3.15.10-201.fc20.i686

libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.2.3-2.fc20.i686

**2)** so when i do command:
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel **3.15.6-200.fc20.i686+PAE** cannot be found at
/lib/modules/3.15.6-200.fc20.i686+PAE/build or /lib/modules/3.15.6-200.fc20.i686+PAE/source.
 [FAILED]
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules [FAILED]

**3)** so cause of 2) i created new ln -s to 3.15.10, doesnt work anyway so when I do:

**/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup**

```
OUTPUT:
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules            [  OK  ]
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS[  OK  ]
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                         [FAILED]
```

and then:
 vboxdrv: version magic '3.15.10-201.fc20.i686+PAE SMP mod_unload 686 ' should be '3.15.6-200.fc20.i686+PAE SMP mod_unload 686 '

**5)** any idea? also my kernel does not match the kernel-devel if you see the BOLD text.
**6)** yum update only updated my chrome.

Comment: You need to install the correct kernel headers rpm as `3.15.6-200.fc20.i686+PAE` for this to work. Make sure the version is correct. possibly do a `yum search kernel-headers` and the `yum install <exact rpm+version string>`.

Comment: thank you @askb but it says nothing to do.

Comment: what is the output of the command `rpm -qa | grep kernel-headers` ? From the output check if you have correct version of the headers, if not, install it using `yum install kernel-headers-<version-str>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked.

```
  617  cp /boot/grub2/grub.cfg  /tmp/
  618  grub2-mkconfig 
  619  grub2-mkconfig  > /tmp/grub.cfg.new 
  627  cd /boot/
  629  cd grub2/
  631  mv grub.cfg  grub.cfg.old
  632  mv /tmp/grub.cfg.new  grub.cfg
  634  reboot
```